# Having a language select option in an app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, localizable.strings

I have Googled this for hours but could find no advice for the following problem (using Swift).

I have seen in many apps an option to select the language from inside the app like this:

[image: Choose your language screen]
<sub>(source: [unity3d.com](http://forum.unity3d.com/attachments/screen568x568-4-jpeg.108285/))</sub>

I would like to achieve something similar, but am having trouble implementing it. I have localized my app and have my Localizable.strings files all set up. I'd imagine it has something to do with storing the language selected in NSUserDefaults, but how can I make the app use the appropriate Localizable.strings file once a language has been chosen? Or is that the wrong way to approach it?

How have others successfully implemented this feature in Swift?

Comment: Maintain a plist file with all these languages as you have already done localization just load the plist with the language selected by user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you go into a bit more detail please? So say I had a variable called languageChosen and set it to "French" for example, how would I use the plist file to call the correct Localizable.strings file?

Comment: Just load the plist NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *customPlistPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"French.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:customPlistPath];

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Using this method though, I assume I can't set text on labels directly using storyboard. I will have to set every label's text programmatically using the relevant plist, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already faced this issue on one of my project and found one solution :

When the user select a language from a list, post a `NSNotification`. All your `UIViewController` subclass must register to this notification and change the labels value according to the new language selected.

You can use the localized strings in order to set the labels, but `NSLocalizedString(...)` shouldn't be called since it's relying on the device language which is different from the application language.

You can find my implementation of a custom localisator on [Github](https://github.com/micazeve/iOS-CustomLocalisator), available both on Swift and objective-C.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just downloaded it and had a quick play, it looks like a really good solution! I think I will try to get this working in my project as it makes use of existing Localizable.strings files. I will come back and mark this answer as correct if it solves my problem.

Quick question though - my app is already live in the app store. If I add localization using your method, will it affect the functionality for existing users of my app? It's a game with scores and progress saved locally on the device using a plist - will there be any issues?

Comment: I used it in a production app which previously used localizable strings and didn't get any issue during the transition : since the default value of this custom localisator is "Device Language", there is no visible change for the user.

Comment: This solution is perfect for me, it's a great piece of code that's easy to integrate into an existing project. I got it working effortlessly. Thanks so much for sharing Michaël. :-)

Comment: I'm glad to know it helped :)

Comment: I am getting an error in a line of your code in Swift 3.0.
`func receiveLanguageChangedNotification(_ notification:Notification) {
    if notification.name == kNotificationLanguageChanged {
      configureViewFromLocalisation()
    }
  }
`
The error is: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') and 'String'. Please could you let me know how to fix this?

Comment: @Eatton : I'm looking at it right now, never tried it on Swift 3.0 !

Comment: @Eatton A new branch was created for Swift 3.0, look can try it now :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! :-) It works perfectly, I appreciate you taking the time to update the code.